# Solving ODE with white noise and Dirac delta function

Tags: r, ode

I would like to solve numerically the following ODEs:

[image]

where W is white noise and delta is the Dirac delta function. If the system only had the terms in p and v, it would be easy to write a code in R. In fact this is my work:

```
# parameters:
parameters <- c(alpha = 1,
                beta = 2,
                kappa2 = 1,
                kappa3 =-1)

# initial conditions:
state <- c(v=0.8,p=0.5)

Lorenz<-function(t, state, parameters) {
  with(as.list(c(state, parameters)),{
    # rate of change
      dv <- -2*alpha*v-beta^2*p
      dp <- v
      # return the rate of change
      list(c(dv,dp))
  }) # end with(as.list ...
}


times <- seq(0, 100, by = 0.01)


library(deSolve)
out <- ode(y = state, times = times, func = Lorenz, parms = parameters)
head(out)


par(oma = c(0, 0, 3, 0))
plot(out, xlab = "time", ylab = "-")
mtext(outer = TRUE, side = 3, "ODE", cex = 1.5)
```

The resulting plots are:

[image]

How can I consider also the presence of white noise and Dirac's delta and then solve the complete equation?

Comment: You will need an SDE solver, such packages also exist in R as they are fundamental for financial simulations. // Assuming the solution is zero for negative times, the delta terms just specify initial conditions for the solution at positive times. (This interpretation is not quite compatible with the stochastic terms.) // You could also reference the [origin of the equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4497949/how-to-approach-a-second-order-ode-with-dirac-delta-and)

Comment: @LutzLehmann, thank you. Could you provide some examples?

Comment: You may also consider the white noise as a time discrete [forcing function](https://tpetzoldt.github.io/deSolve-forcing/deSolve-forcing.html) and then solve it with `ode`.

Comment: Hi @tpetzoldt, I read the reference. Thank you. I think that `Example 1: Time-varying input` could be useful for my task. For example, in the function `SPCmod` of first example (step 3) the object `import` could be the white noise. But how can I include the Dirac's delta?

Comment: Dirac's delta is firstly a theoretical-mathematical construct. To implement in practice, one should firstly be clear on its purpose in a particular model. Then it can either be implemented as a forcing function (a pulse of short duration, but in practice > 0), or as an immediate change of a state, i.e. an event.

Comment: @LutzLehmann: what do you think, would it be feasible to approximate delta with a gaussian curve, similar to the second figure in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function). If yes, I could post an example.

Comment: @tpetzoldt : In principle yes, but depending on the width of it you will need a very high sampling rate. It is easier to just implement the jumps in the state components.

Comment: @LutzLehmann: agreed! If the bandwidth of the signal is set to a small value (e.g. 0.01), then the integration step size drops down (tested by putting a `cat(t, "\n")`  in the model. Implementing this with an event is of course also possible -- and easily done if the OP requests it. I am still uncertain why (and if) it should be at the initial time t=0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**White noise** can be implemented as a "forcing function". A random component within the model function does not work, because it confuses the solver.

In the following examples, white noise is added at a fixed interval of 1. It can technically be implemented as interpolation with `approxfun` or just as a lookup in a vector. The lookup is faster, but I use `approxfun` as the more general approach. The function `W` can then be passed to the model function as additional named argument.

The non-continuous noise signal is a certain challenge for the solver, as it violates the continuity assumption of an ODE, but the `lsoda` solver is quite robust and can handle this well at the cost of small internal time steps.

For **immediate impulses** (that may be described as Dirac's delta), different approaches are possible.

### Approach 1: Approximation by a smooth function (integral = 1)

Here an example, where we approximate delta by a Gaussian function (`dnorm` = normal density function). The bandwidth of the signal can be changed with parameter `sigma` ([cf. Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function)). A rectangular signal would also be possible but a smooth differentiable signal is preferred.

```r
library("deSolve")

model <- function(t, state, parameters, W) {
  with(as.list(c(state, parameters)), {
    
    # approximate delta with a Gaussian that has integral 1
    delta <- dnorm(t, sd = sigma)
    dv <- -2 * alpha * v - beta ^ 2 * p - (kappa2 - kappa3) * delta +
          (beta - 2 * alpha) * W(t)
    dp <- v - kappa1 * delta + W(t)
    # return the rate of change
    list(c(dv, dp), delta = delta, W = W(t))
  })
}

state <- c(v = 0.8, p = 0.5)

parameters <- c(alpha = 1,
                beta = 2,
                kappa1 = 1,
                kappa2 = 1,
                kappa3 =-1,
                sigma = 0.1, # width of the delta approximation (> 0)
                mean = 0     # location of delta, shift parameter 
)


# start with - 100 to show the influence of delta at time t=0
times <- seq(-100, 100, by = 1)

## predefined white noise in **discrete** time
## sd specifies amplitude of noise as standard deviation
W <- approxfun(times, rnorm(length(times), sd = 0.1), method="constant")

out <- ode(y = state, times = times, func = model, parms = parameters, W = W)
head(out)

par(oma = c(0, 0, 3, 0))
plot(out, xlab = "time", ylab = "-")
mtext(outer = TRUE, side = 3, "ODE", cex = 1.5)
```

[image: Model simulation]

### Approach 2: Use of an event function

The idea is to stop the solver at the time point(s) of delta, then to modify the states in an "event function", and then continue numerical integration. This can either be done by chaining calls of `ode` or with the event mechanism implemented in `ode`.

The following code shows an example with several events (impulses) occurring at time steps `timedelta`. A parameter `delta` is used for better visibility in the code, but as it is 1.0 by definition, it can also be omitted.

```r
library("deSolve")

model <- function(t, state, parameters, W) {
  with(as.list(c(state, parameters)), {
    dv <- -2 * alpha * v - beta ^ 2 * p  + (beta - 2 * alpha) * W(t)
    dp <- v  + W(t)
    list(c(dv, dp), W = W(t))
  })
}

## the event function returns instantly modified states
eventfunc <- function(t, state, parameters, ...) {
  with(as.list(c(state, parameters)), {
    c(v - (kappa2 - kappa3) * delta,
      p - kappa1 * delta
    )
  })
}

parameters <- c(alpha = 1, beta = 2, kappa1 = 1, kappa2 = 1, kappa3 =-1, delta = 1)
state      <- c(v = 0.8, p = 0.5)
times      <- seq(0, 100, by = 0.1)
timedelta  <- seq(0, 50, by = 10)
W <- approxfun(times, rnorm(length(times), sd = 0.1), method="constant")

out <- ode(y = state, times = times, func = model, 
  parms = parameters, 
  events = list(func = eventfunc, time = timedelta), W = W)

plot(out, xlab = "time", ylab = "-", mfrow=c(1, 3), which = c("W", "v", "p"))
```

[image: ode output with events]